# Cisco SG300 Switch VLAN issue

Tags: cisco

We've got **Cisco SG300** switch (in L2 mode) which we use to extend our network.

It's **ge10** port is connected to **main switch** (upper level, connected to different PC and Servers with no issues) and has trunk on it for 3 VLANs coming in from main: **Data (112T)**, **VoIP (111T)** and **DeviceMang (150T)**.

Other SG300 ports has setup like this: Data (**112UP** - for Windows PC who cannot tag traffic) and VoIP (**111T** - for IP phone who has no issue with VLANs).

```
    Port Mode     AdmVLAN                      OpVLAN    
    GE1  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE2  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE3  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE4  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE5  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE6  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE7  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE8  Trunk  111T, 112UP                 111T, 112UP     
    GE9  Trunk  1UP                         1UP     
    GE10 Trunk  1UP, 111T, 112T, 150T       1UP, 111T, 112T, 150T
```

We usually connect both PC and IP Phone to the same port (PC through IP Phone). When I do it this way, my PC sees the network with no trouble.

But when I connect my PC directly to switch - PC becomes blind. It can no longer ping anything connected to upper level switch.

The switch itself (SG300) pings upper level devices with no trouble (through web or telnet interface). Also two servers within SG300 section of network sees each other but cannot see anything upper level.

So how to make Windows PCs directly attached to SG300 see devices on upper level switch?

[image: Network Section of interest]

There is an image, hope it helps.

Comment: What IP and subnet masks are assigned to each device (PC1-PC4 and the IP Phone)?

Comment: PC1 to PC4 uses subnet 172.22.223.x with mask /24. IP phones in subnet 172.22.225.x with mask /24. Inter-Subnet traffic is handled by upper level router according to vlan.